# Not able to install ionic on a mac: unexpected eof

Tags: macos, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I am having a problem installing `ionic`.

Cordova was installed, but I am still getting the below error.

```
Bankims-MacBook-Pro:Documents bankimdebnath$ sudo npm install -g cordova ionic

tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-776-1c23f39a/registry.npmjs.org/winston/-/winston-1.1.2.tgz
tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-776-1c23f39a/registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-3.10.1.tgz
tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-776-1c23f39a/registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-2.4.2.tgz
Darwin 15.0.0
argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
node v4.2.2
npm v3.5.0
unexpected eof

If you need help, you may report this error at:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
Please include the following file with any support request:
/Documents/npm-debug.log

Bankims-MacBook-Pro:Documents bankimdebnath$
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of `npm-debug.log`?

Answer (score 0):

try deleting npm package folder and npm install again.

if not try with downgrading node to 0.10.x version.

Comment: Hi, I have tried that also. I downgrade the node which one was working earlier, but now it is not working. If you can give me more idea.

Comment: Hi,again same error after downgrade the node. $ sudo npm install -g ionic
Password:
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-934-8fe97a5f/registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.1.3.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! unexpected eof
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/bankimdebnath/npm-debug.log